# MySQL table doesn't exist but I can see it

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run a legacy PHP/mySQL website on my local machine but I can't get the database queries to work.  If I run a query on just a table it gets the results but if I ask for a column it tells me it doesn't exist.  This is a sample query that works:

```
SELECT * FROM `content_page` WHERE 1
```

This is a query that tells me table doesn't exist, although I know it does

```
SELECT * FROM `content_page.site_id` WHERE 1
```

Again, this is an older website that's running PHP 5.3.1, and I wonder if I'm not understanding something like PDO or the compatibility options I should check when exporting the database?  Forgive my ignorance.

**EDIT:**

A table query works when using

```
SELECT * FROM content_template WHERE id=1
```

as suggested, but using backticks returns the same error.  I'm confused as to why this code would work on their live server but break on mine if the syntax is wrong?

Here's a complete query with the live code that doesn't work for me:

```
$sql = "SELECT content_revision.*, content_template.machine_name AS template_name, content_template.id AS content_template_id,
                    content_page.is_sold,
                    content_page.new_home as new_home,
                    content_page.css_classes,
                    site.domain, site.name as site_name, site.id as site_id,
                    site.facebook_url,
                    site.google_url,
                    site.houzz_url,
                    site.blogspot_url,
                    site.youtube_url,
                    site.hours AS site_hours, site.telephone AS site_telephone, site.toll_free_telephone AS site_toll_free_telephone,
                    site.analytics as site_analytics,
                    site.machine_name as site_machine_name,
                IF(content_revision.id IS NOT NULL, CONCAT_WS('/', site.domain, content_revision.url), '') AS `path`
            FROM content_page
            LEFT JOIN content_revision ON content_revision.id = content_page.publish_content_revision_id
            LEFT JOIN content_template ON content_template.id = content_page.content_template_id
            LEFT JOIN site ON site.id = content_page.site_id
            WHERE $url AND content_page.site_id = $site_id";
```

Thanks very much for your help

**EDIT:** Adding error message

This is the error I get when using the query above

```
SELECT * FROM `content_page.site_id`
MySQL Error: Table 'mckeewpb7.content_page.site_id' doesn't exist

Debug:
0:  
file:   
C:\wamp\www\mckee-down3\apps\dblib.php
line:   
290
function:   
db_query
args:   
0:  
SELECT * FROM `content_page.site_id`   
file:   
C:\wamp\www\mckee-down3\apps\ContentPage.php
line:   
223
function:   
db_query_array
args:   
0:  
SELECT * FROM `content_page.site_id`
2:  
file:   
C:\wamp55\www\mckee-down3\index.php
line:   
81
function:   
getPage
class:  
ContentPage
```

**EDIT**

When the large query above is run on their live server it works somehow, maybe because of how they have their dot notation set up in information schema?  When I run it locally, I get the error above.  The issue seems to be that the code was written on a system that allows the dot notation to access columns and fields?  I do know I'm out of my depth and appreciate the continued input.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but how about `SELECT * FROM content_page WHERE site_id=1`?

Comment: Do proper use of backticks to get your desired result.

Comment: Joachim your syntax works, but why would their live code work on their server but not mine I wonder?

Comment: @phillydigital Could you cut'n'paste the actual error message into the question? The question is getting a bit confusing as to what is the actual error.

Comment: Thanks Joachim I added the error message

Comment: @phillydigital `site_id` is not a table, it's a field, so `SELECT * FROM content_page.site_id` wouldn't make sense. SELECT site_id FROM content_page would. As to your big query (`SELECT content_revision.*, content_t...` that doesn't work, what message does that query give?

Answer (score 2):

Wrong usage of backticks, should be:

```
SELECT * FROM `content_page`.`site_id` WHERE 1
```

Otherwhise MySQL is looking for table `content_page.site_id` which does not exists.

Comment: A comma is `,` I'm not sure what the slanted apostrophe's are called

Comment: It's called "grave accent" - just checked it up. Still learning new things every day :)

Comment: What is this query supposed to do?

Comment: Original post edited to show entire query - I tried the backticks or 'grav' accent but it returns the same error

Comment: its not single quotes friend, its backticks

Comment: I suspect the table content_page.site_id with any number of backticks doesn't exist. content_page is the table, site_id is a field. Selecting * from a field does not make sense in any way.

Answer (score -1):

The first query works as expected, since it is query from a table.

The second query fails AS EXPECTED, since it tries to query from a column.

```
SELECT * FROM `table`.`column_name`
```

It will treat `column_name` as a table name, while treat `table` as a database name.

Comment: Dylan do you have any ideas why this code would work on their live server but not locally??  Maybe I have a compatibility issue?

Comment: are you using the same query with live server? I see from ur post that on line server it is a very complex query, while you tried locally a "SELECT * FROM `content_page.site_id`  ". As I said in my ans, content_page.site_id is a column name, you can't query it.

Comment: Hi Dylan, on live server I just know that the big complex query works, and wonder why the same query doesn't work on my local system with the same database?